# JBoss EAP6 and IIS 7.5 - Cannot get connection using isapi_redirect 1.2.37, which works in JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: iis, jboss, ajp, isapi-redirect

I have an issue, relating to JBoss EAP 6 and IIS 7.5.

I have a configured set up with multiple instances of JBoss EAP 6 e.g. node-a node-b etc.

I have isapi_redirect in place to load balance between these nodes. This works successfully in JBoss 7.1.1. However when I try to run EAP 6, all I get is the following error:

---

**Service Temporary Unavailable!**
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Jakarta/ISAPI/isapi_redirector/1.2.37

---

This is my standlone-ha.xml config:

```
    ....
   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:modcluster:1.1">
        <mod-cluster-config advertise-socket="modcluster" connector="ajp">
            <dynamic-load-provider>
                <load-metric type="busyness"/>
            </dynamic-load-provider>
        </mod-cluster-config>
    </subsystem>
    ....
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.2" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
        <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" redirect-port="8443"/>
        <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
            <ssl name="my_cert" key-alias="my_cert-ssl" password="changeit" certificate-key-file="${jboss.server.config.dir}\certificate\my_cert.jks" protocol="TLS" ca-certificate-file="${jboss.server.config.dir}\certificate\my_cert.jks"/>
        </connector>
        <connector name="ajp" protocol="AJP/1.3" scheme="http" socket-binding="ajp"/>
        <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
            <alias name="localhost"/>
            <alias name="example.com"/>
        </virtual-server>
    </subsystem>
    ....
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-diagnostics" port="0" multicast-address="224.0.75.75" multicast-port="7500"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-mping" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45700"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp" port="7600"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp-fd" port="57600"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp" port="55200" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45688"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp-fd" port="54200"/>
    <socket-binding name="modcluster" port="0" multicast-address="224.0.1.105" multicast-port="23364"/>
    <socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8090"/>
    <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
....
```

---

It does state on Redhat's website, that EAP 6 is tested up until isapi_redirect 1.2.30, but I am using isapi_redirect 1.2.37. Is this the issue?

I'm pulling my hair out, so any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Within the interfaces tag you may need to edit the public interface tag like follows:

```
    <interfaces>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/> 
        </interface>
```

...

The address in the inet-address tag defaults to 127.0.0.1 which would allow access only if you were logged directly into the server.  Changing it to all zeroes allows access from any IP address (local or remote).